What are Zuul's default connect timeout and socket timeout?
Zuul's timeout configuration settings are documented here. However, it doesn't give the defaults.
I'm looking specifically for the default timeouts used when configuration Zuul routes, not service discovery. The timeouts can be overwritten using these settings:
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis
Additionally, I can't seem to find where these settings are used in the source code in the Zuul repo (search link), so if you can help shed some light on where to find their usage, that would be appreciated!
